# Finding and retrieving a component from its container

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

In my swing-based UI, I have a JMenuBar which contains a a series of JMenu and JMenuItem objects. One of the menu-item objects also happens to be a JCheckBoxMenuItem.

Now, while the user can click on this JCheckBoxMenuItem in order to toggle the state of an application level setting, the user (in my application) also has access to a command line API to change the application setting. The details of this command line API are not relevant.

My question is this: When the user goes through the command line API and toggles the state of the setting (a static property / setting that applies to all open instances of my application), I would like to update the "checked / unchecked" property on the JCheckBoxMenuItem. To do this, I can either:

1. Store a reference to the checkboxmenuitem.
2. Traverse the JMenu container hierarchy to find the checkboxmenuitem.

I don't want to use method 1 because in the future, if I have more of these checkboxmenuitems, then i'll have to hang on to a reference to each one.

Method 2 seems cumbersome because I need to do:

```
Component[] childComponents = menu.getComponents();
for(Component c:childComponents)
{
    if(c.getName().equals("nameOfTheCheckBoxMenuItem"))
    {
        componentFound = c;
    }
}
```

Is there a better / more efficient way to find a component in a component hierarchy? Is there maybe a better way to solve this problem in general (changing the state of the jcheckboxmenuitem when the value of a property in my application changes), using say, a PropertyChangeListener (Although my understanding is that these only work on "beans").

Comment: How this String value for nameOfTheCheckBoxMenuItem, is coming to this code thing, just explain that part ? Might be, if what I am thinking is the case then I guess I can explain what to do.

Comment: using the "setName" method. For example:

    JCheckBoxMenuItem aCheckBoxItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem();
    aCheckBoxMenuItem.setName("togglePropertyItem");

Now, is there an efficient way of finding the JCheckBoxMenuItem without holding on to a reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

1) I'd suggest to use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for nicest and easiest workaround for multi_JPanel application

2) then you can imlements

- add [Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) / [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

  ```
         ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {

              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                  if (myCheckBox.isSelected()) {
                      // something
                  } else {
                      // something
                  }
              }
          };
  ```
- add [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html)

  ```
  ItemListener itemListener = new ItemListener() {

      public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent itemEvent) {
          if (Whatever) {
              // something
          }
      }
  };
  ```

Comment: I'm not working with an application that has multiple JPanels. My application is simply a JFrame with a toolbar / menubar / and a table embedded in a scrollpane embedded in a panel which sits in the frame.

Secondly, the ActionListener and ItemListener interfaces are fine to perform an action based on what the user does with the UI control, but my question is, how should I get access to the component and change its state programmatically without holding on to a reference to that UI control. Please let me know if any further clarifications are needed.

Comment: @Siddhartha Shankar not sure what do you trie, because for me (my view and experiences) would be nonsence don't know ComponentHierarchy, if you add random JComponent then use HierarchyListener,